# Unterschied zwischen „etwas“ und „etwa“

Tags: difference

„In einer Pfanne *etwas* Zucker karamellisieren“

Wie viel?

„*Etwa* eine halbe Tasse“

Diese Wörte verwirren mich ohne Ende. Klar wenn „etwas“ als Nomen oder Pronomen verwendet wird wie „ein gewisse *Etwas*“ ist es klar. In viele anderen Fälle aber nicht. Gibt es eine klare Regel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nichts einfacher als das.

***Etwa*** verwendest du, um einer Mengenangabe ("eine Tasse Zucker") hinzuzufügen, dass die Menge variieren darf oder nicht so genau genommen werden sollte:

> Etwa eine Tasse Zucker
>
> Etwa sieben Liter Benzin
>
> Dieser Baum ist etwa 300 Jahre alt.
>
> Etwa drei Jahre noch, dann haben wir's geschafft.

Dies geht auch für die Angabe der Zahl diskreter (einzeln zählbarer) Dinge:

> Etwa 50 Menschen standen in der Schlange.
>
> In dem Sack sind etwa 50 Äpfel.

Stattdessen könntest du auch *ungefähr* sagen. Weitere Synonyme sind *circa* und *annäherungsweise*, doch diese werden seltener und eher in bürokratischen oder technischen Zusammenhängen verwendet.

***Etwas*** verwendest du, wenn sonst keine weitere Mengenangabe gemacht wird:

> Etwas Zucker hinzufügen.
>
> Mit etwas Glück kriegen wir das hin.
>
> Von allem etwas, aber von nichts zuviel.

*Etwas* ist hier gleichbedeutend mit *eine kleine Menge*. Dies geht für Mengenangaben, nicht aber für die Angabe nur ganzzahlig auftretender Dinge:

> <strike>Etwas Menschen</strike>
>
> <strike>Etwas Birnen</strike>

"Etwas Birnen" könnte man eventuell irgendwo in sehr nachlässiger mündlicher Redeweise hören, aber in halbwegs kompetent verfassten Schriftstücken wirst du es nie finden. "Etwas Menschen" hört man nicht mal in mündlicher Sprache. Stattdessen sagt und schreibt man hier:

> Ein paar Menschen
>
> Ein paar Birnen

Comment: Oder "einige Menschen/Birnen", v.a. "einige Schuhe" im mündlichen Ausdruck.